# change x-axis label on zooming with date

Tags: highcharts

I have a graph with many data, more precisely a large amount of data stored by day (this is not looking nice for the user, too many labels).

More precisely the data are stored on the DB in this manner:
date (in format YYYY - MM - DD) - data.

That I would like to do, is to have a default zoom (with large amount of data) with x-axis labels (for example) for weeks, but one time that the user zoom in it changes automatically to days.

Anyone has one idea how can I do it?

Maybe this is a good start:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%e of %b'   
    }
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
}]
```

found here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/datetimelabelformats/

**Edit**

That I would like to show is, for example, an average value when there is week "zoom" and when the user zoom-in (in days view) there is the punctual value. Using only one series (because there are several series on this graph).

Comment: So, to clarify: When zoomed out, you want to display different data than when zoomed in (averages vs actual data)? Any you want this in a single series?

Comment: @NT3RP Exactly, if there is a method that on zoom-out (or in default view) can calculate the average value of n_elementes "on the fly" and placing it in the view (possibly without refresh page), then on zoom-in there are actual data.

Comment: Again, I know how to solve it with a "workaround" (e.g. calculate separately the avg value or using a "button" that on refreshing page change the series on the graph), but I would like to know if there is a method to do this "on the fly"

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to work from the [time-series demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series) on the Highcharts website, as it covers both time-series data, and zoomable data, without overloading the graph with too many labels.

**EDIT:**
In response to the additional detail provided, I do not think that highcharts is designed to display different data on zoom-in/out. It will simply display the available data as is.

If you want to be able to adjust the view of that data on zoom, my suggestion would be:

- Add a listener for the [`selection` event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.selection) and;

  - Create a new, temporary series, hide the old series and show the new one or;
  - Change the existing series by recalculating the values
- Have a separate series for the averaged data, and have a means to switch between full data and averaged data.

It's not the answer you are looking for, but I don't believe there is any other way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: +1 for illustrating a possible solution. But in my case, that I would like to show is a series that have avg values in weeks view and punctual datas in days view. Maybe I haven't give a good explanation in the question, I edit it.